# stream server start error in rosrun

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did the roslaunch for this package gps_meas.launch but I am constantly receiving this error. I have tried fixing it but to no avail. The error is as follows:

```
started roslaunch server http://malik:49380/

SUMMARY
========

CLEAR PARAMETERS
 * /gps_meas/

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    gps_meas (rtklib/str2str)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[gps_meas-1]: started with pid [6312]
stream server start
stream server start error
[gps_meas-1] process has died [pid 6312, exit code 255, cmd /home/asfandyar/gnss-master/rtklib/bin/str2str -in serial://ttyACM0:57600:8:n:1:off -out tcpsvr://:8600 -d 5000 -out file:///home/asfandyar/gnss-master/rtklib/logs/%Y%m%d_%h%M_gps_meas.log __name:=gps_meas __log:=/home/asfandyar/.ros/log/3149aa1c-dfe6-11e2-be64-d067e53f4c7b/gps_meas-1.log].
log file: /home/asfandyar/.ros/log/3149aa1c-dfe6-11e2-be64-d067e53f4c7b/gps_meas-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

The output of my `env| grep ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is as follows:

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/asfandyar/ros:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/home/asfandyar/gnss-master
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66207/stream-server-start-error-in-rosrun/) by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 729 on 2013-06-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Read this thread for the answer

```
http://answers.ros.org/question/67018/process-has-died/
```

---

Originally posted by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) with karma: 729 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3